# Regex capture groups in any order

Tags: c#, regex

I need to capture attribute values from the string like this:

```
att_name1=value1|att_name2=value2|att_name3=value3
```

Attributes can be in any order. Number of attributes is about 50.

I'm aware about lookarounds with which I can **match** the string.
And I wrote the regex that can capture values in particular order:

```
"^att1=(?<g1>\\w+)\\|att2=(?<g2>\\w+)\\|att3=(?<g3>\\w+)$"
```

Is it a way to handle any attribute order?

Comment: Do you care about the attribute name? This part `=(?\w+)` will select all the values

Comment: Edited. SO hided capture group name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\b(\w+)=(\w+)\b
```

to capture names and values of attributes. Matches will hold your values in `Groups[1].Value` and `Groups[2].Value`.

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb(%5cw%2b)%3d(%5cw%2b)%5cb&i=att_name1%3dvalue1%7catt_name2%3dvalue2%7catt_name3%3dvalue3)

Sample regex declaration:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\b(\w+)=(\w+)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Or better declare it outside the calling method as a `private static readonly` field.

In case you only want to match *known* attributes and their respective values, use [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) with [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
att_name1=(?<att_value1>\w+)|att_name2=(?<att_value2>\w+)|att_name3=(?<att_value3>\w+)
```

and then access them with `.Groups["att_value1"].Value`, etc. See a [demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=att_name1%3D(%3F%3Catt_value1%3E%5Cw%2B)%7Catt_name2%3D(%3F%3Catt_value2%3E%5Cw%2B)%7Catt_name3%3D(%3F%3Catt_value3%3E%5Cw%2B)&i=att_name1%3Dvalue1%7Catt_name2%3Dvalue2%7Catt_name3%3Dvalue3).

Comment: I mean (?<group_name>\w+) instead of (?\w+).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot SO removes unmarked tags from the quoted text.

Comment: @optim1st: You are welcome. What about the answer? Does it work for you?

Comment: Almost, it captures only first value because of separator symbol "|". I can do like this: "att_name1=(?<att_value1>\\w+)\\|att_name2=(?<att_value2>\\w+)\\|att_name3=(?<att_value3>\\w+)" but again it doesn't capture values in case of other attribute order.

Comment: My bad, I've looked into Match instead of Matches. Yes, it works for me. ありがとう!

Comment: And a little question - I need to use rx.Matches and then get values from matches[0].Groups["att_value1"], matches[1].Groups["att_value2"], etc (one value in one match), right? Is there a one object from where I can resolve all groups?

Comment: Yes, you can use LINQ: `var rx = new Regex(@"\b(\w+)=(\w+)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled); var resss = rx.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(p => new { name = p.Groups[1].Value, value = p.Groups[2].Value }).ToList();`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've thought. Thanks.